# window.location and condition not working IE, CHROME, SAFARI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a little problem that I would share with you.

I can do a fadout fadin on a whole page by clicking html links. The code is ok BUT when i put the condition only FF browser return OK... IE, Chrome and Safari nothing. Impossible to link HREF with window.location...

Please help me !

Below my code to fadeIn and fadeOut between pages html without condition and with :

Without running ok :

```
(window).load(function() {

    $("#overlay").fadeOut(1500);
    $("a.transition").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("#overlay").fadeIn(1000, function() {
            window.location = linkLocation;

            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

With condition NOK except FF :

```
$(window).load(function () {

    $("#overlay").fadeOut(1500);
    $("a.transition").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        linkLocation = this.href;

        if (linkLocation.contains("index.html")) {

            var e = document.getElementById("overlay");
            e.id = "overlay2";
            $("#overlay2").fadeIn(1000, function () {

                window.location = linkLocation;

                return false;
            });
        }

        else if (linkLocation.contains("medias.html")) {
            var e = document.getElementById("overlay");
            e.id = "overlay2";
            $("#overlay2").fadeIn(1000, function () {

                window.location = linkLocation;

                return false;
            });
        }

        else if (linkLocation.contains("competences.html")) {

            var e = document.getElementById("overlay");
            e.id = "overlay3";
            $("#overlay3").fadeIn(1000, function () {

                window.location = linkLocation;

                return false;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I have trouble with `window.location = linkLocation` for the condition... Why ? I'm novice

Thanks !

Comment: ok i know the problem... Need to replace linkLocation.contains by linkLocation.indexOf !!

Comment: If you have the solution you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using window.location try to create form and redirect to the page you wanted. The code will look something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var f = document.createElement("form");
 f.setAttribute("action", "/userSpace");
 f.setAttribute("method", "POST");
 document.body.appendChild(f);
 setTimeout(f.submit(),3000);
</script>
```

Comment: Why not use `window.location`? That way you described seems like it's much more work than necessary, I personally don't think it's a good idea to create an entire form for a simple re-direct.

Comment: `window.location` works in all major browsers, it's a standard.

Comment: I also faced this problem with window.location. I don't know why it don't work. But this code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is for all the browsers :

```
$(window).load(function(){

$("#overlay").fadeOut(1500); 
$("a.transition").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  linkLocation = this.href;

   if (linkLocation.indexOf("index.html")>= 0){

     var e = document.getElementById("overlay");
     e.id = "overlay2";
     $("#overlay2").fadeIn(1000, function() {

     window.location = linkLocation;

     return false;
   });
 }
```

instead of :

```
 $("#overlay").fadeOut(1500);
  $("a.transition").click(function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();

      linkLocation = this.href;

      if (linkLocation.contains("index.html")) {

         var e = document.getElementById("overlay");
          e.id = "overlay2";
         $("#overlay2").fadeIn(1000, function () {

            window.location = linkLocation;

            return false;
        });
    }
```

I hope it can help you. Thanks !